# How would I format a while(loop)?

Tags: loops, while-loop

I'm having trouble understanding the format a while(loop) uses.

How would I go about making one for example one that computes the sum of all multiples of 5 and 9 between a set range of numbers?

Comment: Not even a mention of the language you're interested in?

Answer (score 1):

```
while STATEMENT:
    CODE BLOCK
```

The basic format of any while loop is such that "CODE BLOCK" is executed as long as "STATEMENT" holds true.

For example:

```
x = 6
while (x > 5) and (x < 20):
    x = x + 1
```

As long as x is greater than 5 and less than 20 x will be incremented by one. The loop will terminate when x is equal to twenty. If I had initialized x to 0, the loop would never enter the block and x will remain zero.

Hopefully that helps